# - IntelliJ Community with Thymeleaf error

Tags: intellij-idea, thymeleaf

Cannot find declaration to go to Thymeleaf Most of code looks like that - simple website

error cant find a website:

Whitelabel Error Page
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.StandardEachTagProcessor' (template: "hello" - line 12, col 15)

In Intellij I can't click reference to resources/templates hello.html - return "hello" with ctrl (is it in the wrong folder?).

```
    public String hello(Principal principal, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("name", principal.getName());
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
        model.addAttribute("authorities", authorities);
        return "hello";
```

Comment: You need IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, see https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html.

Comment: Are you sure its required to have IDEA ULTIMATE to open hello.html  after booy on localhost:8080 in statement return "hello". I understand it couldnt find this object

Answer (score 0):

Found it in hello file not closed " " in few place. You can delete this topic please